# Minimize default calling screen and open an activity on Outgoingcall

Tags: android

I want to start an activity on outgoing call ,
and as activity starts default calling screen should move to background(Minimize) and call and activity should run parallel ,
as i want to display certain data while call in process Which will changes!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i have used broadcast reciver and have set priority of intent filter to 50 , after doing this when i tried to call my activity is coming to front beacuse of itz higher priority and calling screen going to backgound .....but call is not made ,  i want call to be continue along with my activity at front!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BroadcastReciever` for capturing **Outgoing Call** event.

Try [android-broadcastreceiver-tutorial-detect-outgoing-phone-call-event](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/04/13/android-broadcastreceiver-tutorial-detect-outgoing-phone-call-event/)
& [BroadcastReceive](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) links,
it will help you.

Comment: then whats your problem?

Comment: i have use broadcast receiver and it'z working fine but what i want to do minimize the default calling screen and need to show my activity on the screen!!

Comment: try to open your activity `onRecieve()` method of `BroadcastReciever`.

Comment: done with that, activity is getting start but calling screen hiding that activity , after ending call i am able to see that acitivity !

Comment: Try to start activity with this 'Intent intent = new Intent(context, Your_activity.class);
 intent.addFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 context.startActivity(intent);'

Comment: Intent i=new Intent(context,CallActivity.class);
i.putExtras(intent);  i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i); have done this only

Comment: i have used same code , it;z true my acitvity is come to front and calling is going back , but you should notice one thing call is not getting connect as calling activity is getting pause that time !

Comment: i think u cant stop call activity. u r asking about minimize that activity so i have answered your que.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22401709/custom-incoming-outgoing-call-screen-in-android   last answer to link made my work :) thanks btw . now my activity is coming to front and call is also getting connect :)